# Entity Framework Database First - Relationships

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, database-first

I think I have CodeFirst understood. Now I know database first EF design is targeted for existing databases, but if I were to quickly go in and create a new database in management studio and create some tables, is it normal that you would create relationships for the tables in management studio or in the edmx designer, I tried in the edmx but got errors when I went to debug. What is the best practice here and what are the correct steps to create Associations between tables if I were to do it in the designer and how does the database in management studio know to update? Any tips/advice is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In times that the entity is updated, try to <kbd>Run Custom Tool</kbd> your model to avoid errors. just <kbd>Right Click</kbd> your model and <kbd>Run Custom Tool</kbd>.